# Android - Loop and filter on List?

Tags: java, android

I have a `List` of data like this :

[image]

I need to get first and last records are same :

[image]

And my model is :

```
public class Modeltest {
    private String lat;
    private String lng;
    private String date;
    private String firstTime;
    private String lasttime;
    private String counts;
    private String userCode;

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }
     .......
       .....
          .....
}
```

I can getting first and last :

```
    List<Unprocessed_DistanceTime_D> listCDM = QDB.DistanceSelect_D();
    int count = 1;
    boolean flag = true;
    int index;
    for (int i = 0; i < listCDM.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (listCDM.get(count).getDate().equalsIgnoreCase(listCDM.get(i).getDate()) &&
                listCDM.get(count).getLat().equalsIgnoreCase(listCDM.get(i).getLat()) &&
                listCDM.get(count).getLng().equalsIgnoreCase(listCDM.get(i).getLng()) &&
                listCDM.get(count).getCounts().equalsIgnoreCase(listCDM.get(i).getCounts())) {
            if (flag){
                index = i;
                flag = false;
            }
        }else {
            index = i;
            flag = true;
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

But my problem is here. How I can add these in another list and add single records in it ?

I get the first and last record then add in another list (I wrote the model above) .

[image]

I should fill my list here :

```
    if (flag){
        index = i;
        ///HERE
        flag = false;
    }
}else {
    index = i;
        ///HERE
    flag = true;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by creating another list? You are getting the values. What else do you need?

Comment: I need to save in a new list and use for compute time and point etc...

Comment: This is quite an unclear question. Please be more specific about what criteria the strings that you want to store in the new list need to fulfill.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to detect flanks (different adjacend entries) and on hit insert both in the new list? On top of that keep very first and very last always. Should do the job.

Comment: Do you want to "group by" just the last "column" or do you want to "divide" out rows that aren't consecutive?

Comment: I need to time,lat,lng,date,usercode of first and last items that are same and merge them i one list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a brute force method that first groups all the entries by a locally defined `Identity` and than merge those groups into a single `Modeltest` object.

There is probably a better way to do this though, since this disregards the fact that the input data is sorted.

```
List<Unprocessed_DistanceTime_D> list = ...;    

class Identity {
    private final String lat;
    private final String lng;
    private final String date;
    private final String counts;

    public Identity(Unprocessed_DistanceTime_D model) {
        this.lat = model.getLat();
        this.lng = model.getLng();
        this.date = model.getDate();
        this.counts = model.getCounts();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int code = 0;
        code ^= lat.hashCode();
        code ^= lng.hashCode();
        code ^= date.hashCode();
        code ^= counts.hashCode();              
        return code;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if(other == null)
            return false;
        if(!(other instanceof Identity))
            return false;

        Identity io = (Identity) other;

        return lat.equalsIgnoreCase(io.lat)
            && lng.equalsIgnoreCase(io.lng)
            && date.equalsIgnoreCase(io.date)
            && counts.equalsIgnoreCase(io.counts);              
    }
}

List<Modeltest> models = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Identity::new))
    .values().stream()
    .map(group -> { // Convert groups into single Modeltest
        if(group.size() == 1) { // Case for single entries
            Unprocessed_DistanceTime_D e = group.get(0);
            return new Modeltest(e.getLat(), e.getLng(), e.getDate(), e.getTime(),
                e.getTime(), e.getCounts(), e.getUserCode());
        }

        // Case for more entries 
        group.sort(Comparator.comparing(Unprocessed_DistanceTime_D::getTime));

        Unprocessed_DistanceTime_D first = group.get(0);
        Unprocessed_DistanceTime_D last = group.get(group.size() - 1);

        return new Modeltest(first.getLat(), first.getLng(), first.getDate(),
            first.getTime(), last.getTime(), first.getCounts(), first.getUserCode());
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an idea for an algorithm. You can probably modify to your needs and fill in the details.

```
    List<Unprocessed_DistanceTime_D> newListCDM = new ArrayList<>();
    if (! listCDM.isEmpty()) {
        Unprocessed_DistanceTime_D firstInGroup = listCDM.get(0);
        Unprocessed_DistanceTime_D lastInGroup = firstInGroup;
        for (int i = 1; i < listCDM.size() - 1; i++) {
            Unprocessed_DistanceTime_D current = listCDM.get(i);
            if (inSameGroup(firstInGroup, current)) { // current belongs to the same group
                lastInGroup = current;
            } else { // new group
                // add old group to new list
                newListCDM.add(firstInGroup);
                if (lastInGroup != firstInGroup) {
                    newListCDM.add(lastInGroup);
                }
            }
        }
        // add last group to new list
        newListCDM.add(firstInGroup);
        if (lastInGroup != firstInGroup) {
            newListCDM.add(lastInGroup);
        }
    }
```